# Best Ruby library for building an API client for a proprietary XML API

Tags: ruby, xml, api

It seems like most (or all) of the ruby API client builder gems assume you're working with a REST API. I need to build a client library for a clunky old API that uses a proprietary combination of SOAP and XML-RPC. What is the best library available for helping me build this client library?

Comment: What did google tell you when you asked that?

Comment: Ruby's XMLRPC library is pretty simple...  Did you already disqualify that for some reason?

Comment: Update: turns out what I need is not XML-RPC but something more like SOAP that allows me to work with custom XML requests/responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this post which has a [nice tutorial for creating a custom SOAP API client](http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/3-rolling-your-own-ruby-soap-client-with-typhoeus-and-nokogiri) using Typhoeus and Nokogiri. The principals described in the tutorial can be applied to any protocol, not just SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

require "xmlrpc/client"

it come from the stdlib

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/XMLRPC/Client.html

Comment: thanks, I realized what I need is not XML-RPC, but rather something custom.

Comment: if you want something custom Sinatra is your best friend ;)